# DataTable live scroll not performed after sorting by a column

Tags: sorting, primefaces, datatable, scroll

I have been searching for a while to find a solution for DataTable live scroll problem after sorting by a column.

First I found that "the columns" should have fixed width:

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1333

Then I found that scrollRows should be used instead of rows

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1236

Although I have made those changes, I couldn't manage to put live scroll after sorting by a column.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks & Regards.

```
<p:dataTable  id="simulationProductDtId" emptyMessage="#{msgs.notFoundSimulationDetail}" var="item"
         value="#{SimulationResultProductBean.simulationSummaryDetailList}"
         scrollable="true"
         scrollRows="25"
         scrollHeight="350" 
         liveScroll="true"
          resizableColumns="true" 
         style="border-bottom:1px solid #427CC7; overflow:scroll;position: relative;max-width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden"
         rowStyleClass="#{(SimulationResultProductBean.collapseSuperCode and item.gam) ? 'row' : null}"
          selection="#{SimulationResultProductBean.selectedSimulationDetail}" selectionMode="multiple"
         rowKey="#{item.id}">
          <f:facet name="header">
                                                  ...
          </f:facet>
          <p:column sortBy="#{item.productCode}" width="40"
                          rendered="#{DynamicSimulationTableBean.columnRenderedMap['productCode']}">
                         <f:facet name="header">
                               <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.code}"/>
                          </f:facet>
                          <h:outputText value="#{item.productCode}" >
                                 <f:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true" groupingUsed="false"/>
                         </h:outputText>
           </p:column>

           <p:column sortBy="#{item.productName}" style="width:100px"
                           rendered="#{DynamicSimulationTableBean.columnRenderedMap['productName']}">
                          <f:facet name="header">
                             <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.description}"/>
                          </f:facet>
           </p:column>
          //Other columns with fixed widths...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a LAZY solution with a reminder on the top of the datatable:

```
    <script> 
    function liveScroll(){
         simulationProductDt. scrollOffset = 25;
     }
    </script>
     <!-- UPDATE scrollOffset value in the liveScroll method when scrollRows is changed!-->
    <p:dataTable  id="simulationProductDtId" emptyMessage="#{msgs.notFoundSimulationDetail}" 
                         scrollable="true" scrollRows="25" scrollHeight="350"  liveScroll="true" 
                        ...other properties


         <p:ajax  event="sort" update="simulationProductDtId" onstart="liveScroll()" onerror="alert('ERROR!')" />
     </p:dataTable>
```

Hope this helps to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late to answer, but I would like to share a solution that I have implemented because I didn't find any code that resolves the problem using primefaces 5.2.

```
<p:dataTable id="entitiesTable" ...widgetVar="wtable" scrollRows="3" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true"... >
    <p:ajax event="filter" update="entitiesTable" oncomplete="resetScrollPos();" />
    <p:ajax event="sort" update="entitiesTable" oncomplete="resetScrollPos();" />
</p:dataTable>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetScrollPos(){
        PF('wtable').scrollOffset=0;    
        PF('wtable').scrollBody.scrollTop(1);   
        PF('wtable').allLoadedLiveScroll = false;               
    } 
</script>
```

The key is set de param allLoadedLiveScroll to false in order to obtain all data again after a filter response or a sort action. Ajax events are configured to reset the parms of the dataTable scroll widget.

Hope this helps to somebody with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your primefaces version, datatable in primefaces seems to be a very unstable component.

I am using version 3.4 with sorted columns but I never tried to make a live scroll. I use the page scroll.
Check your browser too, Internet Explorer is quite unstable.

Comment: Hi ddp, thank you for the answer, but I am using the latest stable version (pf 3.4.2). The project is running on Chrome. Live scroll with many records ,like this situation, kinda fails

Comment: Hi,

I found out that _scrollOffset property keeps incrementing (by scrollRows size) ALTHOUGH it is being scrolled.

_scrollOffset SHOULD BE the value of scrollRows. I couldn't reach to that variable via jquery. 

How can i reach and change _scrollOffset when the datatable is being sorted? (_scrollOffset can be viewed at the FormData header defined by CLASSNAME_scrollOffset at the debugger console)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SerhatTR's anwser nailed it, almost. :)
The client side scrollOffset needs to be reset on liveScroll tables before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

As its mentioned in accepted answer `scrollOffset` is a property on client side Datatable widget object i.e, `widgetVar` not found on `id`.

```
<p:dataTable id="tableId" widgetVar="tableWidget" >
   <p:ajax event="sort" update="tableId" onstart="resetScrollPos()" />
   ...
</p:dataTable>

<script type="text/javascript">
    fucntion resetScrollPos(){
        tableWidget.scrollOffset = 25;
    }
</script>
```